# another slideshow within a slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'd like to know if it's possible to embed an animated slideshow within a slideshow instead of an image? Basically I have a piece of design of which there are multiple versions of it which I want overlapped over each other so I have made a simple jquery slideshow to do that (based on [this tutorial](http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow)), but I want it as part of my design page's own slideshow (animated gifs did the trick in principle but were either too large or poor quality)...

I would appreciate your help and patience!

Comment: I'm a little confused. Did you mean that you have a slideshow on a portfolio page, and one of the things in the portfolio is to demonstrate a slideshow? In that case, I would think the portfolio page itself already shows that you can do a slideshow. So maybe a slide could just mention that.

Answer (score 0):

its posible but you have to develop your own gallery cause all free internet jquery gals only display pictures, or videos...an idea for that its download a simple gallery and insert it in another gallery, for example the simple jquery gallery in your link, make some gals and insert each in [anything slider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) with this you should insert a slideshow within aother slideshow...